# Get HTML source code from browser control embedded in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a browser control embeded in a C# windows app. I want to grab the rendered HTML (which could have been modified by javascript) not the original one.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>You can get the HTML, and indeed set it, with [`WebBrowser.DocumentText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx).</strike>

Sheng is correct, `DocumentText` returns the streamed document before scripts run. His code doesn't compile, but it's essentially correct. I found that you need:

```
mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
string html = doc.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

Comment: Also make sure to only retrieve the document text after the DocumentCompleted event fires (otherwise there's a race condition)

Comment: for using mshtml; you need to add Microsoft.mshtml to your project refrences.

Answer (score 6):

DocumentText internally use the document's IPersistStream interface which returns the original HTML. Use webBrowser1.Document.DocumentElement.OuterHTML instead.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this. I've corrected my answer. I would have deleted it, but you can't delete an accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

Add a Navigated event to your WebBrowser.  Only then will your document be filled.

```
    private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(webBrowser1.DocumentText);
    }
```