# Get full source of a webBrowser

Tags: c#

I have a webBrowser:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = @"<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title></title>
<style type='text/css'>
    .red
    {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class='red'>red text</div>
   sad adad a das
</body></html>";
```

I want to get the full source of the webBrowser:

```
textBox1.Text = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
```

But it results only:

```
<HTML></HTML>
```

It works if I display in a MessageBox before set the textBox1.text:

```
MessageBox.Show(webBrowser1.DocumentText);
```

It's weird. How can I get the full source?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get HTML source code from browser control embedded in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267184/get-html-source-code-from-browser-control-embedded-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proper way to display HTML from string in `WebBrowser` control

```
var html = @"<html lang='en'>
    <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title></title>
    <style type='text/css'>
        .red
        {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class='red'>red text</div>
       sad adad a das
    </body></html>";

webBrowser1.DocumentText = "0";
webBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(true);
webBrowser1.Document.Write(html);
webBrowser1.Refresh();

// Will return html you provided
textBox1.Text = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain a bit? Why does not enough the `webBrowser.DocumentText` ?

Comment: @kovak I think the HTML you're trying to set to `webBrowser.DocumentText` is not parsed correctly by `WebBrowser`. I checked it in debug mode and found a lot of exceptions inside.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your initial question directly, how to get FULL SOURCE no matter what:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HTML").Item[0].OuterHtml;
```

Make it a habit to use this and NOT DocumentText because if you make any changes to DocumentText after it's been set, for example, changing the InnerHTML of a tag, those changes wont save to DocumentText.

I just slapped a TextBox onto one of my WinForms and updated the text to the above code and it shows all my HTML without issue.  Here's an example of me filling in my WebBrowser in case you've got a typo or something in your code:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
WebBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(false);
WebBrowser1.Document.Write("<html><head><title></title></head><body></body></html>");
```

I never had any luck writing the DocumentText directly.  This method worked without issue.